# What might ((virg)) mean in a radio broadcast transcript?

Tags: vocabulaire, radio

I listen to RFI's Français Facile podcast and noticed that right when they play the little opening melody they have for it, the transcript says `((Virg))`.

What might that mean?

Comment: Very likely *virgule*. What that means is less self-evident. A pause/breath?

Comment: That was my guess as well but I hadn't seen it used that way before! Edited question slightly to fix error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C'est une abréviation de *virgule*. Le mot est utilisé ici dans un sens technique précis. En radiophonie, une *virgule* est une séquence sonore courte (quelques secondes) qui établit une séparation courte durant une émission. Ce peut être un bruitage ou une mélodie instrumentale, quelquefois accompagnée de quelques mots. Une émission utilise en général toujours le même son, et ce son est même souvent partagé entre plusieurs émissions sur une même chaîne.

L'étymologie est assez claire. Le sens radiophonique vient du sens musical (qu'on trouve dans les bons dictionnaires généralistes) : une courte pause qui laisse au joueur d'un instrument à vent ou au chanteur le temps de respirer. Ce sens dérive évidemment du sens habituel de la virgule comme élément typographique indiquant une courte pause.

L'équivalent du point — un effet sonore plus long, souvent entre deux émissions — s'appelle un [jingle](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/jingle) (prononcé à l'anglaise).

---

It's an abbreviation for *[virgule](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/virgule)*. It uses the word in a very specific technical sense. In radio broadcasting, a *virgule* is a short sound sequence, lasting a few seconds, that marks a short separation within a program. It can be a sound effect or a purely instrumental melody (or more rarely it can include a few words). The same sound is generally used throughout a given program or during many programs on the same station. It is both intended to give the presenter some time to breathe and to give the listener a reminder of the program or station they're listening to.

The etymology of the word is from the sense in music, where it's a short quiet interval during which the player of a wind instrument or the singer can breathe. And that, of course, derives from the meaning of *virgule* as a sign to mark a pause in speech.

A longer sound effect or musical passage (the equivalent of the full stop), typically between programs, is called a [jingle](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/jingle) (pronounced like the English word, just with a French accent).

---

Exemples d'usage et de définitions :

- [Sons et éléments d’écriture radio](http://cache.media.education.gouv.fr/file/CLEMI/23/1/Lexique-Ecriture-radio_480231.doc)
- [*Libération* — Radios : la loi du jingle — « Lexique : les Habits de radio »](http://www.liberation.fr/ecrans/2011/09/19/radios-la-loi-du-jingle_957445)
- [Définitions marketing — virgule sonore](https://www.definitions-marketing.com/definition/virgule-sonore/)
- [24h dans une rédaction : l'habillage du journal](https://www.24hdansuneredaction.com/radio/15-lhabillage-du-journal/)